# Find $\bigcup\limits_{n∈N} A_{n}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$\bigcup\limits_{n∈N} A_{n}$ for $A_{n} = \{x∈R|x^2-nx>0\}$

From my understanding:

$x^2-nx=0$

$x(x-n)=0$

$x=0$

$x=n$

So:
$x^2-nx>0$ when $x<0$ or $x>n$

$x∈(-∞;0) U (n;+∞)$

So the union of these sets should be the set with the most elements? So since $x∈N$, the smallest x could be 0.0001 or 0.0000001. This is the part I'm having trouble with.

Any help or tip would be appreciated!

Comment: I guess N stands for the set of natural numbers. For you, is zero a natural number?

Comment: @Senna Yes, N is for natural numbes. For me 0 isnt part of N

Comment: In that case, $\cup_n A_n = (-\infty , 0) \cup (1,+ \infty)$. Note that the greatest $A_n$ is for $n=1$.

Comment: Note that $A_{n+1}\subset A_n$ so the infinite union is just $A_1$.

Answer (score 1):

You have come quite far on your own. The final stretch is concluding how the set must look like once forming the union over all n:

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}_{+}$, then $x^{2}-nx=x(x-n)>0 \iff (x>n \lor x<0)$, therefore $A_{n}=(-\infty,0)\cup(n,\infty)$. Hence $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}_{+} : A_{n+1} \subseteq A_{n}$ and obviously $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}_{+} : A_{1}\supseteq A_{n}$. If $A_{1}$ is the first set and contains all the others, then it is invariant to the union with later sets.

Thus, $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}_{+}}A_{n}=A_{1}=\mathbb{R}\setminus{[0,1]}$

Answer (score 0):

First note if $x$ is negative,  $x^2-nx>0$ is always true for $n\in\mathbb N$.

And if $x$ is positve $$x^2-nx=x\cdot (x-n)>0$$ is equivalent to $$x-n>0.$$
Thus for any $n\in\mathbb N$ you get,

$A_n=\mathbb R^{-}\cup \{x\in\mathbb R^{+}\colon x-n>0\}=\mathbb R^{-}\cup \{x\in\mathbb R^{+}\colon x>n\}$.

Can you make it from here? Try to compute $A_1,A_2,A_3$. Now you should see $A_n\subset A_1$ for any $n\in\mathbb N$ and therefore $\bigcup_n A_n=A_1$